# Gnuplot set logscale y axis e base

Tags: gnuplot

it's my first question here, i wanted to ask if there's a particular way to use the
`set logscale <axes> <base>` command,
using the euler number e as base, because i found out that if I don't write any base, it automatically chooses the 10 base, which is not what i need. can someone help me please? I also discovered i can use the command

```
plot 'Mydata' using 1:(log(x))
```

but I'd obviously prefere not to use it because there is the other one made for this..

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Euler's constant directly, like:

```
set logscale y exp(1)
```

The axis ticks won't be nice though, but I'm not sure if you require this.

Comment: But Euler's constant has infinite digits, stopping at that 5 wouldn't be incorrect? i mean obviously gnuplot cannot use infinite digits, but maybe there's a better variable recognised by gnuplot that fits best.. isn't it?

Comment: @SimoneBaldisserri you won't ever notice this on a limited-resolution screen, even if it's 4K or 8K, even on paper, unless all your values are _very_ close to each other.

Comment: you're right, i haven't thought about it thanks a lot :)

Comment: `set log y exp(1.0)` would give you however much precision is available (about 15 decimal places).